# Sending JSON array to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I get this error when trying to send JSON array to PHP, not really sure what I missed. Appreciate it if anyone could help. I know this question is a bit repetitive but I've tried most of them still doesn't work.

> Undefined index: T_DrugAllergy

** In PHP file **

```
$arrDrugAllergy = stripcslashes($_POST['T_DrugAllergy']);
$arrDrugAllergy = json_decode($arrDrugAllergy,TRUE);
```

** Jquery code **

```
     var T_DrugAllergy =  JSON.stringify(getDrugAllergySpecified());
        alert(T_DrugAllergy);
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('postMedicalRecordsCreate', ['id' => 0]) }}",
            type: "POST",
            data: { T_DrugAllergy : T_DrugAllergy },
            success: function(data){
                console.log("success:",data);
            },
            failure: function(errMsg) {
                console.error("error:",errMsg);
            }
        });
```

- T_DrugAllergy is my array.
- getDrugAllergySpecified is a function where I store my values into the array.

Here's an image, shows when I do alert(T_DrugAllergy), the array contains 2 records which is indeed what I want, so I am not sure why get that error.
[alert(T_DrugAllergy)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGwGK.png)

Comment: can you try: `data: { "T_DrugAllergy": T_DrugAllergy },` as well, you can inspect your POST request

Comment: @ChristopheHubert Still get the same error